# Use Excel Trim in C#

Tags: c#, trim

somebody can i help me? I need import a sheet to DataGridView and later export to Excel. But i wish use the function TRIM before the import to DataGridView. My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFile.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Documents";
        openFile.Filter = "Microsoft Excel |*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xls |All Files (*.*)|*.*|Text (*.csv)|*.csv";

        if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            txtFile.Text = openFile.FileName;
            this.btnImp.Enabled = true;


            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + openFile.FileName + ";" +
            "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

            //HERE MY ASK
            var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Range["A2:A460"].Formula = "=TRIM()"; 

      OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Plan1$]", conn);

            da.Fill(ds);
            vGrade.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];


            conn.Close();

        }


    }
```

This code below doesn't works. I never worked with 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'

```
 //HERE MY ASK
            var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Range["A2:A460"].Formula = "=TRIM()";
```

The error is : An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in SisE400.exe Additional information: Exception the HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

I just want to TRIM "A2:A460" from my sheet excell. How do i do it? What's the syntax?What's the subject? Please help me.

Comment: This code isn't complete.  Where is `excelApp` defined, for instance?  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also, you are calling `excelApp.Range["A2:A460"].Formula = "=TRIM()";` but then you don't save it and close it before loading it via OLDEDB.  How do you expect that to work?

Comment: Do you know the column names? If yes, can we use ltrim(rtrim(col_1)) in the select statement itself? Just a thought

Comment: Sorry I forgot paste it, was 'var excelApp = new Excel.Application();'

Comment: My column 'A' is 'Code'.

Comment: The error is : An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in SisE400.exe

Additional information: Exception the HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: Check my solution below. Replace Col 1 with "A"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this... worked for me..

I have created two columns "Col 1" and "Col 2"

```
private static void ReadExcel()
    {

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            "Data Source=Z:\\Codes\\Test1.xls;" +
            "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

            var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select LTRIM(RTRIM([Col 1])) AS [Col 1],LTRIM(RTRIM([Col 2])) AS [Col 2] From [Plan1$]", conn);

            da.Fill(ds);
           // vGrade.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];


            conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: It's works in parts because um code with numbers, special characters and letters will be white in DataGridView or with just numbers. Example: 1450928 N > 1450928 (DataGridView) or 02.01.8973-27 > ' empty white in DataGridView'

Comment: My code only trims trailing and leading spaces. What are you looking for???

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to use `TRIM()` to trim values and save them back to the original location.  The way excel formulas work, you'd need to use a *different* range to store the trimmed value, and reference the original cell in that formula.  Something like:

```
excelApp.Range["B2"].Formula = "=TRIM(A2)";
```

Note that 1) this puts the trimmed value in a different column (overwriting whatever was there) and 2) it works for a single cell - I don't know of you can apply a formula to a range and it will replicate automatically.

An easier method may be to trim the data in C# instead of using Excel interop:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + openFile.FileName + ";" +
            "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

using(OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Plan1$]", conn))
{
    da.Fill(ds);
}

foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    dr[0] = dr[0].ToString().Trim(); // trim the value in the first column and save it back

vGrade.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

conn.Close();
```

Comment: Error 1 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataSet' because 'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' C:\Users\Home\Desktop\SisE400\SisE400\Form1.cs 48 21 SisE400

Comment: Error 2 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Trim' and no extension method 'Trim' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Home\Desktop\SisE400\SisE400\Form1.cs 49 39 SisE400

Comment: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot convert type 'System.__ComObject' to 'System.Data.DataRow''